# JavaScript contains part of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a problem. Here is a string:

```
var string = "somethingthatidontneed"
```

and I created an array of substrings which I want to check if they are in `string`.

```
var arrString = ['some', 'that', 'dont']
```

And the thing is that I want to get every character that doesn't match the pattern of words from `arrString` and count them. So in this case I would like to receive number 10 (because of words: 'thingineed').

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: so, you want to strip var string of the words found in arrString? look at string replace method in a loop perhaps

Comment: Where are you facing difficulties?

Comment: This will do it: `arrString.forEach(str => { string = string.replace(str, '');});`. Then simply do `string.length` to get the count.

Comment: In a place of getting number of characters that dont fit the pattern from array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keeping what you need, you cam remove all the unwanted occurrences using `String.replace`. You need a regular expresion with the `global` modifier so that if a string occurs multiple times, all occurrences are removed.

Note that this modifies the original string.

```
var string= "somethingthatidontneed";
var arrString=['some', 'that', 'dont'];
arrString.forEach(function(s) { 
 string = string.replace(new RegExp(s, 'g'), ''); 
});
console.log(string); //out: "thingineed"
```

Comment: or `string = string.replace(new RegExp(arrString.join('|'), 'g'), '')` - no loop :p